# Is there a more concise way to pass function result as shown here

Tags: c++

I'd like to call my function that creates the object to be passed to a method on the same line, but if I do I get an **initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue** compile-time error. To get it to compile I need to declare a temporary holder variable and set it equal to the factory method resul.

I realize this is because the reference is simply an address of a storage location, but is C++ really not able to recognize the construct and create a temporary holder variable? I am not a great C++ coder, so I assume I am missing something or that there is a gap in my knowledge, or both - and I hope you can help. I am using GCC, and C++ 11, with VS Code as my editor.

```
class Bar {};

class Foo {
  const Baz add(Bar& bar) { /* .... */ }
};

void doIt() {
   Baz baz;
   // what compiles...
   Bar bar = createBar();
   baz.add(bar);

   // What I'd like... but it gives me "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue"
   // baz.add(createBar());
}
```

Comment: You could change `add` to take a `bar const &`, or just `bar`, and then you can call it with a temporary.

Comment: To be clear, baz::add is not modifying bar at all, but is adding it to a vector after some checks. I am using reference in order to avoid additional copying. I realize in some cases pass by reference makes the compiler think it is modifying. I didn't add the const to baz::add srgument because that seems to cause issues when adding to the container.

Comment: Fast response, thank you.  bar const &  or const bar & ?

Comment: I'll bet that once you enable the compilers optimizer, your intermediate variable will be optimized out entirely. So it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: They're equivalent, but I strongly prefer `bar const &`.

Comment: "bar const & or const bar &" - no difference. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. If you do an answer I'll go ahead and select it.  I am curious too why you prefer bar const & .

Comment: @BillBarnhill Because it's less confusing. If `const bar&` means "reference to `const` `bar`", then it "stands to reason" that `const bar*&`  means "reference to `const` `bar*`. But the actual meaning is, if you read from the where the name should be (right of `&`, outwards), "reference to pointer to `bar` `const`ant". Writing it `bar const&` makes it more obvious that "reference to `const` pointer to `bar`" is actually `bar *const&`. It also fits with the reading direction: `bar const &b` says "`b` is reference to `const`ant `bar`; `const bar &b` says "`b` is reference to `bar` `const`ant."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the signature to:

```
Baz add(Bar bar) { /* .... */ }
```

1. Since you need to retain the value (to put it in a vector) you must have ownership of the object.  You've declared that you take a reference to avoid making a copy, but you *do* make a copy -- when you put it in the vector!

   Instead, take the object by value, and then the caller can *move-construct* the argument, and `add()` can *move-construct* the vector element.  (C++17 further guarantees move-elision in some of these cases, so the object could be directly constructed in the vector.)
2. There is no point in returning the `Baz` object as `const` since it's not yours anymore; the caller can decide if they want to receive it as `const`.

Your `doIt()` becomes:

```
void doIt() {
    // Argument is move-constructed from the temporary.
    baz.add(createBar());
}
```

In your method:

```
Baz Foo::add(Bar bar) {
    // Perform your checks, then...
    the_vector.emplace_back(std::move(bar));

    return some_baz;
}
```

The general advice is that if your function needs to take ownership of an object, it should receive it *by value.*  This allows the caller to decide what they want to do: make a copy because they still need the original, or move the original into the argument and let the callee steal the state.